# Can't type in text fields everywhere

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, locking, textfield

**I was working on a client site but found a problem that text fields are locked or can't type in it**, just looking good means blinking normally if you click on text fields (but can't type).

A simple query but not looks like a simple one to me!

Comment: Is this an actual question?  If so......what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of your javascript plugins is interfering with your input values.  If you disable javascript on the page then you can actually type or even right click on the page to inspect elements.  My suggestion is disabling your plugins one at a time to see which one is interfering.

Comment: Thanks for you help, i found a piece of code which was interfering with form fields.